# bug in payuindia gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, payumoney

i was using payuindia gem for integrating indian gateway to my app

https://github.com/payu-india/payuindia/blob/master/lib/payuindia.rb

It seems there is a bug in the code in checksum verification. The logic to compare the hash seems to be wrong. I want a second eye to verify this. I appreciate your help.

The hash depends on a list of fields. The ordering of items in the two list are not consistent. For example in the first list txnid is first but in the second list txnid or invoice is last. Also in the second list there is transaction status but in the first list there is no transaction status. The hash will be same if both of these lists are consistent. Please correct me if i am wrong.

```
CHECKSUM_FIELDS = [ :txnid, :amount, :productinfo, :firstname, :email, :udf1, :udf2, :udf3, :udf4,
                        :udf5, :udf6, :udf7, :udf8, :udf9, :udf10 ]


checksum_fields = [transaction_status, *user_defined.reverse, customer_email, customer_first_name, product_info, gross, invoice]
```

Is this a bug? Thanks for any feedbacks.

Comment: I believe you will get quicker response if you create an issue for this on gem repo

Comment: thanks i have already added an issue and hoping to get a response from the author.